# Android transfer touch event between views

Tags: android, touch

Here is my issue.

I have about 7 buttons inside a linear layout and i am trying to "slide" between them highlighting each one as the finger passes over.

So far i have seen that the view that receives the action down event is locked in and receives every following motion event untill action up.

here is what i was trying:

```
public class LinearRoot extends LinearLayout {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = LinearRoot.class.getSimpleName();

    public LinearRoot(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
    }

    private LinearRoot(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
    }

    private void init() {
    getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            getChildAt(i).getHitRect(r);
            Log.e(TAG, r.flattenToString());
            map.put(r, getChildAt(i));
        }
        LinearRoot.this.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        }
    });
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
     */
    View lastView;

    private final HashMap<Rect, View> map = new HashMap<Rect, View>();

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        return false;
    }
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    if (lastView != null) {
        lastView.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
        if (dispatchTouchToSpecificView(rect, ev)) {
        lastView.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return false;
        } else {
        ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        lastView.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    Iterator<Rect> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        rect = iterator.next();
        if (dispatchTouchToSpecificView(rect, ev)) {
        lastView = map.get(rect);
        map.get(rect).dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }

    private boolean dispatchTouchToSpecificView(Rect r, MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.e(TAG, "X: " + (int) ev.getX() + " Y" + (int) ev.getY());
    Log.e(TAG, r.flattenToString());
    return r.contains((int) ev.getRawX(), (int) ev.getRawY());
    }
}
```

This is the root layout for all the buttons, which delegates the touch events to the appropriate button by getting its global hit rectangle and seeing if the touch event is inside.

Right now this works only partially, and i am not satisfied with the solution, please provide some comments or possibilities to try.

What i am trying to achieve is a layout that has a large number of buttons which are pretty small and i want to highlight the touched ones before the release so the user can adjust his click.

Comment: I doubt it'll be much help, but Android 4.0 introduces hover state events which might solve this for you.

Comment: Well i need this to work for android 2.1 and above.